# I want range for specific value in excel

Tags: excel

I want range for specific value in excel as,

my values

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

and suppose compare value is 2.5. If 2.5 is value then it should return range 2 and 3 in separate row for further calculations. Similarly i input value is 5.2 then it should return range 5 and 6 in separate row for further calculations

Answer (score 0):

Cell E6 is the place where you have enter the value

`=IFERROR((--LEFT(E6,1))&"-"&(--LEFT(E6,1)+1),"0-0")`

if entered value is 5.5 the output will be 5-6